# Checking if string is complety shown in popup window

Tags: java, android, string, popupwindow

Is there a standard way to do this? My popup window has maxsize and I would like to cut the string if it is too long.
Currently I'm doing

```
   if(txt.length()>320)
        {
            txt = txt.substring(0,320)+"...";
        }
```

but this seems crude and doesn't work sometimes because of paragraphs.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve with the text to be shown

Comment: There is no standard way. You don't get feedback about how much data is actually displayable inside the screen.

Comment: to give  a quick overview.
No feedback huh . ok . Is there a good way to calculate how much string would fit ín the popup ? because the max size changes with the screensize.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499698/trim-a-string-based-on-the-string-length. Check this answer. Might be helpful to use `Math.min`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define below property to textview.

> android:ellipsize="end"