# How do you cut a string to a desired size?

Tags: java

The method in question looks like:

```
Public static String cut (String s, int size){
    Return "";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trim a string based on the string length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499698/trim-a-string-based-on-the-string-length)

Answer (score 0):

There is `String.substring()` to cut off a string.

Example of how to use:

```
"hamburger".substring(4, 8) returns "urge"
"smiles".substring(1, 5) returns "mile"
```

In your case it would be:

```
"hamburger".substring(0, 4) returns "hamb"
```

Docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)