# Limiting/Removing extra characters (>40) from string. 

Tags: java, string, trim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [up to first N characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583940/up-to-first-n-characters)
>   [I need to “trim” my variable called: “TITLE” to only 40 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533692/i-need-to-trim-my-variable-called-title-to-only-40-characters)

Java: Limiting/Trim/ Removing extra characters from string.  I want to remove any extra characters after 40 characters of a string variable.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 2):

```
String shortString = longString.substring(0, Math.min(longString.length(), 40));
```

You might like to take a closer look at the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) class