# Android Copy String Like Delphi Copy's Function

Tags: android

Example 1:
`i Have an Apple`
Example 2:
`I Love U`

i would like to copy 10 string only, start index from first character.
Delphi code would be like this :
`copy('I Have an Apple',0,10)`
`copy('I Love U',0,10)`

Result become
`i Have an`
`I Love U`

Any same function in Android?
no method how long the string, i just want the first 10 character

Answer (score 1):

You're probably after [`.substring(int start,int end)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) which applied to your code, would be something like the code below, however when you say you would like to copy *"10 string only"* you should say 10 characters from said string:

```
String apple     = "i Have an Apple";
String appleCopy = apple.substring(0,10); // "i Have an "
```

If you want to handle the IndexOutOfBoundsException inline, you could do this, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583940/up-to-first-n-characters), which would take the first `n` characters if the length is sufficient, or the whole string if its shorter.

```
String appleCopy = apple.substring(0, Math.min(apple.length(), 10));
```

Comment: if string shorter than 10 chac, will be error with out of index or not?

Comment: It will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException if start < 0 or start > length(). It's up to you to handle it. See my edit for a simple way of handling it.