# Reformatting String That Is an Android Version Number

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm trying to reformat a string in java and remove the final decimal out of an android version number, so 4.2.2 would be formatted to 4.2.

Would I use REGEX to get the desired format for the android version number?

Here's my code for finding the android version number:

```
String osRelease = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wIeI.jpg [Error Log File From Eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

Just use some String manipulation:

```
String i = "4.2.2";
String s = i.substring(0, Math.min(s.length(), 3));
System.out.println(s);
```

This will give you the first 3 characters (ie. "4.2") of your input String).

If you have your value as a `Double` or similar, use `String.valueOf(myDouble)` to convert to String.

---

<sup>`Math.min()` trick is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1583968/4428462).</sup>

Comment: I don't get any errors in my code when I run this, but my app won't start with this code included.

Comment: @pHorseSpec, Do you see anything in LogCat when you try to start app ? Try printing out the version without modifying it.

Comment: based on the value returned, a certain picture is displayed. Here's the code for the if statement: `if (MainActivity.osReleaseDouble>4.3){mPhotoPool.add(R.drawable.download);}else{mPh‌​otoPool.add(R.drawable.negative);}`  My error log file is in the above question.

Comment: @pHorseSpec, why do you even use a double ? Just get the a api level via `Build.SDK_INT` and use that. That's what you're supposed to do.