# java regular expression extraction of first n characters from an alphanumeric String

Tags: java, regex

How to extract first 3 characters from an alphanumeric string in Java?
For example- if the alphanumeric string is 12A12D3F34DFdHNB38HG. So I want to extract ADF

Comment: What about the code you use? Also, non accentuated Latin letters are not the only alphabetic characters...

Comment: [String.substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

Comment: Post your code. This regex should work fine.

Comment: Seeing as `String`s consist entirely of `char`acters, it's not clear what you mean by "*it only works if the string is starting with a character*". Please include what you've tried so far and a clear description of the problem you're running into. "It doesn't work" isn't something we can diagnose.

Comment: You may use Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]{3}")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [up to first N characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583940/up-to-first-n-characters)

Comment: It can be done with an easy [`s.replaceAll("(?i)^[^a-z]*([a-z])[^a-z]*([a-z])[^a-z]*([a-z]).*$", "$1$2$3")`](https://regex101.com/r/uD5cO0/1).

Comment: Wiktor Stribizew- Thank you, its working

Answer (score 0):

To extract the first three characters of a String, you can simply use the substring() method in the String class.

```
String firstThreeCharacters = str.substring(0, 3);
```

If this was not what you are asking for, please clarify your question since it is arguably ambiguous.

EDIT: @Wiktor Stribiżew has a good answer for your clarified question. I'm re-posting it here to make the answer more visible for other users.

```
String firstThreeCharacters = str.replaceAll("(?i)^[^a-z]*([a-z])[^a-z]*([a-z])[^a-z]*([a-z]).*$", "$1$2$3")
```

Comment: actually i have a alphanumeric string. For eg-A12D3F376HF7H23H87JH. So I want to extract first three alphabets so i want the output to be ADF

Answer (score 0):

You need pattern as : `[a-zA-z0-9]{3}`

Comment: no this pattern extracts first three characters,be it number or be it alphabet. I want to extract only alphabets